# What system menus are available?

Tags: menu

- Hello, just visiting.

Based on this: 'https://www.howtogeek.com/748310/whats-new-in-elementary-os-6-odin', I'm considering EOS. The type of menu system is a large factor in my decision.

I've taken a tour of sorts and read about EOS and Pantheon and Vala, etc., but I've not seen menu(s). I'm currently running a Mint Guest (Win10 Host) and find Cinnamon Menu lacking.

Comment: What do you mean by system menu? A start menu like windows? elementaryOS has an application menu on the top left that shows a list of all installed apps.

Comment: System menu: The thingy you open when you want to run a listed app.

(I'm learning that use of the 'W'-word in Linux forums causes unrest.)

Do you know of an EOS-architecture description of the menu system? Is it based on '~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop' files? Can things other than applications be put in the system menu? Can there be submenus and sub-submenus, etc.?

Comment: The applications menu will only show applications and not folders. However there are categories so you could edit the desktop files and set a specific category for some apps if you're keen on having some sort of folder.

Comment: Regarding .desktop files, most of them are inside `/usr/share/applications` (system wide) instead of the local folder for each user. You can create custom files with commands and anything you need and they should appear on the applications menu as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Maccer. It sounds like fly-out submenus (and sub-submenus etc.) are not possible. That seems the same as Cinnamon Menu and is the major reason I don't run Linux as the Host OS. Oh, well...